# Form errors not appear in a custom form theme with EasyAdmin3

Tags: php, symfony, twig, easyadmin

I overrided my form in EasyAdmin to organize differently my input so I did like this :

In my Crud :

```php
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 'admin.menu.infos')
            ->setFormThemes(['bundles/EasyAdminBundle/crud/company/edit.html.twig'])
            ;
    }
```

And in my Twig :

```
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/crud/form_theme.html.twig' %}
{% use '@EasyAdmin/symfony-form-themes/bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.logo) }}
        {{ form_row(form.phone) }}
        {{ form_row(form.catchphrase) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.businessName) }}
        {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        {{ form_row(form.website) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.companyName) }}
        {{ form_row(form.address) }}
        {{ form_row(form.linkedin) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.siren) }}
        {{ form_row(form.zipcode) }}
        {{ form_row(form.facebook) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.legalForm) }}
        {{ form_row(form.city) }}
        {{ form_row(form.twitter) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.description) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

The form is like I wanted and when I submit, it's work but the problem is when I make an error. For example if I valid with an empty value, then instead of getting my form_errors, I've got a 500.

I've tried different things but none of them worked :

- block errors :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% block form_errors %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
```

- individual error :

```
{{ form_errors(form.businessName) }}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have this problem without override theme? I doubt that is the problem...

Comment: Yes only when I override

Comment: Have you any log about the 500?